# Automatically opening ports?

Tags: java, sockets

When I install any other program, I don't have to manually open any ports, yet when I write a program (in java) using sockets, it won't work until I manually open those ports. Am I missing something here? Is there some technique to open those ports automatically? Perhaps some ports that I can use that are always open? (seems weird to me). Any advice is welcome.

```
    int port = 7000;

    Socket s = new Socket(ipAdress, port);

    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String str = "", str2 = "";
    while (!str.equals("stop")) {
        str = br.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(str);
        dout.flush();
        str2 = din.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Server says: " + str2);
    }

    dout.close();
    s.close();
```

client^

```
    int port = 7000;
    int id = 1;

    ServerSocket loginserver = null;
    try {
        loginserver = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("LoginServer started...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while (true) {
        Socket clientSocket = loginserver.accept();
        ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++);
        cliThread.start();
    }
```

server^

Comment: Please post some code showing what you are currently doing.

Comment: @AndyTurner There's nothing, just creating a socket in java which listens for some input from a client. (Used the Oracle tutorial). It works with localhost but when I try it on a different network then I need to open the port that I use manually. When I install any program (for example a game) that makes a connection over the internet I don't usually have to open those ports manually. I'm just wondering what's going on, and how I can make it so that the user does not have to open any ports manually.

Comment: Literally no code at all? No wonder those ports aren't opening. Seriously, you must have some code that you are trying to run, otherwise you are simply asking why <nothing> isn't doing <specific thing that you want>.

Comment: @AndyTurner okay okay, I've put the code in the op.

Comment: There's some more code. extend thread that keeps user ID and a function for printing and sending but I think it's irrelevant

Comment: It's about the connection. If I don't open the ports manually, it will give an error: refused connection

Comment: Just to clarify, by "opening ports", do you mean allowing them through your firewall or something like that?

Comment: @vesan yes, that's what i meant

Comment: @JentevanHeuverswyn I'm not an expert on this, but I would expect that creating firewall exceptions is usually done by the installer. If you're distributing your software using an installer, you might want to look into that.